# iOS 7 TableView dequeue not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having a really annoying problem that I'm not sure WHY it's happening.

I have the Table view set, I have the correct Identifier in the Cell, but it still gives me "unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard" when I run it.

the code looks like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *event = [self.events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [event objectForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;
}
```

Any help would be great, cause I want to rip my hair. The table is connected to that class, and then Cell has that @"Cell" Identifier

Comment: Where did you create the cell and set the identifier to `Cell`?

Comment: Can you provide screenshot of xib or storyboard file.

Comment: I will when I get home, but it's the same place as the screenshot already posted below. You click on the Cell, and then in the attributes tab I typed in "Cell"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Re-check all 4 steps**

**STEP 1:**
Your cellForRowAtIndexPath should look like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier   forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
}

NSDictionary *event = [self.events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [event objectForKey:@"name"];

return cell;
}
```

**STEP 2:** Your "ViewController.m" File should look like this

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

**STEP 3:**
PLEASE CHECK - Click on view controller move to Connection inspector - See if any other unwanted connections are present in this inspector.

[image: Your Controller inspector should like this]

**STEP 4:** Tableview cell attribute inspector should like this]

[image: Your Tableview cell attribute inspector should like this]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Try:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

if that does not work after

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

add:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right, you need to register a cell for reuse. This can be done programmatically after you've created your table view like this:

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
[tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

Or this can also be done in Interface Builder by selecting the cell and navigating to the attributes inspector and changing the cell's id.

Comment: I already did that, it has the same string in the Identifier as the one in the code...but it still says "unable to dequeue..."

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking for cell is allocate or not.. You can try below code..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    // add a placeholder cell while waiting on table data

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
    } 
}
```

Comment: If the cell is registered properly then dequeue will create a cell for you if required so checking and manual creation is not required...

Answer (score 0):

In the Document Outline, verify that your prototype `UITableViewCell` is a child of the `UITableView`.[image: Storyboard Document Outline]

In the Attribute Inspector, verify that your Cell Identifier  and Cell Style are properly set in storyboard:

[image: storyboard screenshot of Table View Cell attribute inspector]

In the Identity Inspector, verify that you have the class set to `UITableViewCell`:
[image: storyboard screenshot of Table View Cell identity inspector]

Comment: and the prototype cell in the Identity Inspector has your class set? Your statement "the _table_ is connected to that class" in your question is a bit sloppy. You need to connect the prototype cell to your `UITableViewCell` subclass.

Comment: ok, so what I meant was that I have an EventTableViewController.h and m files. in the storyboard, I have under the Attribute tab "EventTableViewController" as the class associated with the Table Viewcontroller on the storyboard

Comment: ok, so let us take the exception message literally. Do you have a prototype cell in the UITableView? What style (see "Basic" above) does your cell use?

Comment: I tried all of them, none of them work. I'd like to use the Subtitle, though

Comment: I understand now that you are not using a `UITableViewCell` subclass. I added a screenshot from the Identity Inspector. Is your Class set to UITableViewCell as in the screenshot?

Comment: no, still same issue, and yes, that does show in the Class attribute. It works if I create my own cell (if (cell == nil)....) but I thought iOS5+ didn't require that, the dequeueing caught that automatically. I tried creating a new test project, using the basic tableviewcontoller and creating an array to bind to each cell and that works just fine, I just don't know why it doesn't work in THIS project. does it matter that it's in a navigation controller?

Comment: I have it in a NavigationController and it works just fine. I was about to propose to you to create a new test project that is based on the master-detail template and then compare with what you have got in your project, but apparently you already did that. I added an image of the desired document outline to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %d",indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = nil;

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        NSDictionary *event = [self.events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [event objectForKey:@"name"];

    }

    return cell;
}
```